# Pagination with multiple groupings

Tags: data-structures, pagination

I have a data model that looks like this:

```
Group 1
--Sub group1
----item1
----item2
----item3

--Sub group2
----item1
----item2
----item3

Group 2
--Sub group1
----item1
----item2
----item3

--Sub group2
----item1
----item2
----item3
```

There will be n number of each group and I would like to display this data on screen.

A requirement is to use paging but I am a little unsure of how to effectively page when there are these groupings involved. Ordinarily I would just retrieve the next n records and append to the existing set but will need something a little more complicated.

Does anyone have any experience doing something like this? I don't want to grab entire sub groups at a time as they may contain too many or too few items, and would like to be consistent by pulling the same number of items each time.

Comment: Is this about designing the software implementation of adding new records to a grouped list like this, or about the user experience of whether it makes sense to do this kind of grouping on unfinished data sets?

Comment: Its more about the approach from a programming point of view

Comment: What happens when your `page size` is `10` items but `Group 1` has a total of `5` sub-items and `Group 2` has a total of `7`?  Does `Group 2` get included in the page?  Does it get omitted?  Or does it get truncated only to be resumed on the next page?  These are important UX questions so I think you should start from a UX point of view first.  That will help better define the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Ideally I would like to bring ten back regardless of group, if group 1 has nine, then these will be displayed plus the first from group 2.